# Unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported! - causes importing cpp_extension

Tags: gcc, c++

Then I import it says before error this:

```
/home/dex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:118: UserWarning: 

                               !! WARNING !!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Your compiler (c++) may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch!
Please use a compiler that is ABI-compatible with GCC 4.9 and above.
See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html.

See https://gist.github.com/goldsborough/d466f43e8ffc948ff92de7486c5216d6
for instructions on how to install GCC 4.9 or higher.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                              !! WARNING !!

  warnings.warn(ABI_INCOMPATIBILITY_WARNING.format(compiler))
```

But following gist  trying to install 4.9 and 5.9 same errors
Cant get installed, also on 18.04 but with other error:

```
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for dex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.24.32.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

 Toolchain test builds; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                  
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
0% [Release.gpg gpgv 1 189 B] [Connected to download.docker.com (52.222.250.2
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
dex@dexpc:~$ 
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-5.9 g++-5.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.9'
E: Unable to locate package g++-5.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-5.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5.9'
```

dex@dexpc:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0

Comment: Why can't root open sources.list?  Without that, it's not surprising you cannot find normal packages.

Comment: @ubfan1 I think you right how can I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a copy of sources.list at  /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list   Copy your /etc/apt/sources.list to save the ppa changes you entered and start with the fresh copy.  Then run the

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then add in your ppas from your saved copy of sources list, and repeat the

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Just in case, here's the contents of the fresh file:

```
# See sources.list(5) manpage for more information
# Remember that CD-ROMs, DVDs and such are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
```

Comment: i think there is some kind of symbolic links so cant even edit it
dex@dexpc:~$ sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list: editing symbolic links is not permitted. File sources.list already persist in the both locations